# adding header to multicolumn listview in android

Tags: android, xml, listview

I tried the following question in this forum  [Adding Header in Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110949/how-to-add-header-to-multicolumn-listview)

but the problem is same I've used a linearlayout having three textview as header to my multicolumn listview but the problem is that the columns do not align themselves under the header how can I give separate header to each column of multicolumn listview

or

Is there an open source implementation of multi column list available which supports column headers??
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

consider using [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

- It provides a lot of convenience methods when you are dealing with 'sections' in listview.